# Subaru Legacy cam belt change

Tags: engine, subaru, timing-belt, belt, legacy

I have got a 2010 Subaru Legacy 2.5 GT and it has done 90,000 KMs now. What is the best time to change its cam/timing belt? Is it by 100,000 KMs or 100,000 Miles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.subarupacific.com/recommended-105000-mile-service.htm) (and another site I saw), the change interval for your Subie should be at **105k miles**.